# more on creating dictionaries of dictionaries

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I am a novice and learning about dictionaries in python, and spent better part of a day wrapping my head around it, I would appreciate some help!

I would like to create a dictionary of dictionaries:

```
data = [['dog', 'a'], ['mouse', 'a'], ['dog', 'b'], ['mouse', 'c'], ['dog', 'c']]
animals = ['dog', 'mouse']
```

I would like to do this:

```
final = {'dog': {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, 'mouse':{'a': 0, 'c': 0} }
```

So far I have this code, which obviously is not working:

```
animal_dict = {}
for d in data:
    animal_dict[d[0]] = {}

letter_dict = {}
for animal in animal_dict:
    for d in data:
        if d[0] == animal:
            letter_dict[d[1]] = 0
            animal_dict[animal] = letter_dict

print animal_dict
```

Notice that it is adding an extra key ('b') in the 'mouse' dictionary. I know I am making it more complicated than it should be! Thanks in advance for helping a novice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only really need one loop:

```
data = [['dog', 'a'], ['mouse', 'a'], ['dog', 'b'], ['mouse', 'c'], ['dog', 'c']]
animals = {}

for animal, letter in data:
    animals.setdefault(animal, {})[letter] = 0
```

Or if you don't like `setdefault`:

```
for animal, letter in data:
    if animal in animals:
        animals[animal][letter] = 0
    else:
        animals[animal] = {letter: 0}
```

Or with `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict:

animals = defaultdict(dict) # creates a dict when the key doesn't exist

for animal, letter in data:
    animals.[animal][letter] = 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much Blender! :) I learned a lot from these posts.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting both `animal_dict['dog']` and `animal_dict['mouse']` to the same `letter_dict` object. Any keys you add to one will be added to the other.

You do not actually need `letter_dict`. Try this instead:

```
for animal in animal_dict:
    for d in data:
        if d[0] == animal:
            animal_dict[animal][d[1]] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for i in data:
...     if i[0] not in d:
...             d[i[0]] = {i[1] : 0}
...     else:
...             d[i[0]][i[1]] = 0
... 
>>> d
{'mouse': {'a': 0, 'c': 0}, 'dog': {'a': 0, 'c': 0, 'b': 0}}
```

You're using the same dictionary to put both the dog and mouse values in, hence the extra 'b' key, because there would already be a 'b' from the dog. You could create an `if/else` statement to differentiate each.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same `dict` when adding it to the `animal_dict` hence why there is an extra *b* key. You should check if the `animal in animal_dict` and if it isn't then add the new key with a empty dict.

```
for animal in animal_dict:
    if not animal in animal_dict:
        animal_dict[animal] = {}

    for d in data:
        if d[0] == animal:
            animal_dict[animal][d[1]] = letter_dict
```

Another option is to use a [defaultdict documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). That would remove the need for the key check in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you love how many different ways there are to do things in Python?  :-)

You can also just move creation of letter_dict inside the outer loop:

```
for animal in animal_dict:
    letter_dict = {}    # Create new letter_dict for each animal
    for d in data:
        if d[0] == animal:
            letter_dict[d[1]] = 0
            animal_dict[animal] = letter_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty, the animals list is unnecessary really.

```
d = {}
for animal, letter in data:
    if not d.has_key(animal):
        d[animal] = {}
    if not d[animal].has_key(letter):
        d[animal][letter] = 0
```